# Small children doing crimes

Tags: practical-islam

In reality and legally, punishment for crimes should depend upon the age of a person. If he is a minor, the punishment should be less severe.
What happened with me was I was invigilating and some kid cheated on a board exam. Since he was small and young and I didn't want to ruin his life, I let him go?
In Islamic point of view how should children be punished and did I do the right thing?

Comment: If I would have reported the child, he would have gotten a ban and a severe punishment which would have negative effects on his development.

Comment: While you may have saved him from immediate harm you have encouraged his behavior and have harmed those who gave their test honestly. In Islam yes children should be corrected by firstly to persuade them softly, then warn them, then scold them, then punishment as in the hadith on salah.

Comment: I couldn't bear to see the small child being punished and his future ruined. If possible I would have warned him. Thanks a lot

Comment: Before asking questions that have been asked before do a good research on the site.